# Website shows no source code when using React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a website that shows no source code. It was built using React.

Can anyone think of reasons I can check?

Answer (score 5):

There is source code, however, it is most likely all compiled into one bundle. I would go to that web page and view the page source, then at the bottom of the the page (right around `</body>`), you'll most likely see the compiled js file there.

Though, even if you do find the file, there really wouldn't be a point to it that I can imagine because most of the code would React imports and nothing related to that webpage.

But anyways, that's where the source is (most likely).

Comment: I understand exactly what you said thank you but it doesnt help me. For some reason I have no source code and its causing me SEO issues. I was wondering if this was maybe a common occurrence and somebody had an answer.